# Turn denormalized json dataframe column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble to parse a csv file formatted like this:

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  event_type  |                         event_properties                         |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Event type 1 | {"event_type_1_property_1": "a", "event_type_1_property_2": "b"} |
| Event type 2 | {"event_type_2_property_1": "1", "event_type_1_property_2": "2"} |
| Event type 1 | {"event_type_1_property_1": "c", "event_type_1_property_2": "d"} |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Each event type has its own properties in the json column.

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

df_new_columns = pd.DataFrame(df['event_properties'].values.tolist())
df = pd.concat([df, df_new_columns],axis=1)
```

But df_new_columns is not as expected it is just the same as df['event_properties']

I would expect the following df:

```
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|  event_type  | event_type_1_property_1 | event_type_1_property_2 | event_type_2_property_1 | event_type_1_property_2 |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Event type 1 | "a"                     | "b"                     | None                    | None                    |
| Event type 2 | None                    | None                    | "1"                     | "2"                     |
| Event type 1 | "c"                     | "d"                     | None                    | None                    |
+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve that?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Check the version of Pandas you have installed, upon trying `pd.DataFrame(df['event_properties'].values.tolist())` it generated the columns precisely as you are looking for them (pd.__version__ = 1.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code that does exactly what you want :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
["event_type_1",'{"event_type_1_property_1": "a","event_type_1_property_2": "b"}'],
["event_type_2",'{"event_type_2_property_1": "1", "event_type_1_property_2": "2"}'],
["event_type_3",'{"event_type_1_property_1": "c", "event_type_1_property_2": "d"}']],
columns = ["event_type","event_properties"])

# This line if your columns is loading as a string
parsed = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df["event_properties"].map(lambda d : json.loads(d)).values.tolist())

# This line if your columns is loading as dicts directly
# parsed = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df["event_properties"].values.tolist())

pd.merge(df["event_type"],parsed,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

I was not sure if the read_csv loaded directly the 'event_properties' columns as dict so I assumed it was loaded as string. Please let me know if that solved your issue.